# MySQL won't start, dependency errors?

Tags: apt, dpkg, mysql

On Ubuntu 12.04.  This is a very old utility AWS server that has always run reliably.  Today I notice that MySQL isn't running.  I did a reboot just to be "clean".  When I try and issue:

`/etc/init.d/mysql start >/dev/null 2>&1 &`

I get:

```
[1] 10836
```

Not sure what this means.  I notice that there is a pending software update for `w3m` and so I use 
`apt-get -y install w3m ..`

and get

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server-5.5:
 mysql-server-5.5 depends on mysql-server-core-5.5 (= 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2); however:
  Version of mysql-server-core-5.5 on system is 5.5.54-0ubuntu0.12.04.1.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server-5.5 : Depends: mysql-server-core-5.5 (= 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) but 5.5.54-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I've tried googling this issue and these results but see no solutions.  I've checked the MySQL error logs, and they are all zero bytes.

What's up?

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt-get update` to make sure the package catalog is up to date? You *might* get some helpful diagnostic information if you remove the redirections to /dev/null

Answer (score 0):

does updating the system help ie. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

it looks like the version mysql-server-core-5.5 it needs **5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2** is not the one it thinks is available **5.5.54-0ubuntu0.12.04.1**

a system update may help satisfy the dependencies. 
cheers,